# How to wrap VictoryBar with the container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

Is it possible to wrap each VictoryBar with the container?

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-cloud-gyt8i

[image]

I want to see something like this:
[image]

And also be able to add some elements inside this container.

P.S. I also opened the same issue on GitHub: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/issues/1904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

We can create an additional `VictoryBar` with `dataComponent` prop and pass a custom component. This custom component can use victory primitives such as `Box`.

An example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-pasteur-uj1m3